# Return 400 Bad Request if version specified in header does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-web-api2

I'm writing a Web API and I'm implementing versioning using routing constraints, similar to how it is done in the Web API 2 sample which is located [here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/RoutingConstraintsSample/RoutingConstraints.Server/VersionConstraint.cs).

I have an implementation of IHttpRouteConstraint similar to the one below. I noticed that a 404 is returned if I pass a version in the request which doesn't exist, after Match is invoked for each Controller with the route attribute which has the constraint.

I'd like to return a different error in this case. Possibly a 400, with a custom message. I'm not entirely sure how to do this.

All this web stuff is quite new to me.

**Edit**: Just to clarify. The problem I'm having is I'm not really sure how to test for this case and where to throw/return the error.

```
/// <summary>
/// A Constraint implementation that matches an HTTP header against an expected version value.
/// </summary>
internal class VersionConstraint : IHttpRouteConstraint
{
    public const string VersionHeaderName = "api-version";

    private const int DefaultVersion = 1;

    public VersionConstraint(int allowedVersion)
    {
        AllowedVersion = allowedVersion;
    }

    public int AllowedVersion
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpRequestMessage request, IHttpRoute route, string parameterName, IDictionary<string, object> values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (routeDirection == HttpRouteDirection.UriResolution)
        {
            int version = GetVersionHeader(request) ?? DefaultVersion;
            if (version == AllowedVersion)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private int? GetVersionHeader(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        string versionAsString;
        IEnumerable<string> headerValues;
        if (request.Headers.TryGetValues(VersionHeaderName, out headerValues) && headerValues.Count() == 1)
        {
            versionAsString = headerValues.First();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

        int version;
        if (versionAsString != null && Int32.TryParse(versionAsString, out version))
        {
            return version;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't violate HTTP protocol. 400 is explicitly dedicated to cases when header _syntax_ is wrong. The code most closed to the situation when you understand a request but refuse to fulfil it due to constraints is 403. Also, 412 can be used (not properly but with much lesser violation than 400). Please keep in mind you can add any additional headers to explain details to your clients.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Request.CreateErrorResponse in WebApi to return a custom status code:

```
return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, 
                    new UnauthorizedAccessException("not Authorized."));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My problem isn't really how to create the response. It's more like where should I return/throw it. I should clarify in the question.